# While loop synchronization

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, semaphore

I am working on a project with a user defined number of threads I am using 7 at the moment. I have a while loop that runs in each thread but I need all of the threads to wait for each other at the end of the while loop. The tricky thing is that some of the threads do not all end on the same number of times through the loop.

```
void *entryFunc(void *param)
{
    int *i = (int *)param;
    int nextPrime;
    int p = latestPrime;
    while(latestPrime < testLim)
    {

        sem_wait(&sem);
        nextPrime = findNextPrime(latestPrime);
        if(nextPrime != -1)
        {
            latestPrime = nextPrime;
            p = latestPrime;
        }
        else
        {
            sem_post(&sem);
            break;
        }

        sem_post(&sem);
        if(p < 46341)
        {
            incrementNotPrimes(p);
        }
/*
        sem_wait(&sem2);
        doneCount++;
        sem_post(&sem2);

        while(go != 1);

        sem_wait(&sem2);
        doneCount--;
        //sem_post(&sem3);
        sem_post(&sem2);
*/
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

where the chunk of code is commented out is part of my last attempt at solving this problem. That is where the functions all need to wait for each other. I have a feeling I am missing something simple.

Comment: You need the threads to wait for each other after each finishes the while loop? In this case you could put the semaphore wait right after the while loop.

Comment: Use a barrier instead of a semaphore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you should use a barrier instead of a semaphore for this kind of situation, as it should be simpler to implement (barriers have been designed  exactly to solve that problem). However, you may still use a semaphore with a little bit of arithmetic
arithmetic: your goal is to have all thread execute the same code path, but somehow the last thread to finish its task should wake all the other threads up. One way to achieve that is to have *at the end of the function* an atomic counter which each thread would decrement, and if the counter reaches `0`, the thread simply calls as many time `sem_post` as necessary to release all the waiting threads, instead of issuing a `sem_wait` as the others.

A second method, this time using only a semaphore, is also possible. Since we cannot differentiate the last thread for the others, all the threads must do the same operations with the semaphore, ie try to release everyone, but also wait for the last one. So the idea is to initialize the semaphore to `(1-n)*(n+1)`, so that each of the `n-1` first threads would fail at waking up their friends with `n+1` calls to `sem_post`, but still work toward getting the semaphore at exactly `0`. Then the last thread would do the same, pushing the semaphore value to `n+1`, thus releasing the locked threads, and leaving room for it to also perform its `sem_wait` and be released immediately.

```
void *entryFunc(void *param)
{
  int *i = (int *)param;
  int nextPrime;
  int p = latestPrime, j;
  while(latestPrime < testLim){
    nextPrime = findNextPrime(latestPrime);
    if(nextPrime != -1)
    {
        latestPrime = nextPrime;
        p = latestPrime;
    }
    if(p < 46341)
    {
        incrementNotPrimes(p);
    }
  }
  for (j=0;j<=THREAD_COUNT;j++)
    sem_post(&sem);
  sem_wait(&sem);
  return NULL;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it doesn't deal with how the semaphore should be reset in between uses (if your program needs to repeat this mechanism, it will need to reset the semaphore value, since it will end up being `1` after this code has been executed successfully).

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that on each thread, the while loop has a different numbers of iterations and some **threads never reach the synchronization point after exiting the loop**, you could use a barrier. Check **[here](http://tuxthink.blogspot.ro/2013/01/ussing-barriers-in-pthreads.html)** for an example.

However you need to decrease the number of threads at the barrier after you exit each thread. Waiting at the barrier will end after **count** number of threads reached that point.

So you need to update the barrier object each time a thread finishes. And make sure you do this atomically.